# Finding the most optimal combination of parts

Tags: scala

I have a list of parts for a vehicle.
I also have a list of combinations of parts that product a given power rate.

So given a list of parts, I need to find the most optimal combination that products the most power.

```
case class Part(id: Int, power: Int)
case class PartCombo(parts: List[Part], power: Int)
```

So for example there might be 2 parts that have power 1, but when these parts are together they have a power of 3.

So given a list of parts, I need to see if these parts belong to any part combo's, and if there are multiple combos, I need to choose the one that products the most power.

What is the best way calculate this?

Comment: this is a typical optimization problem where you need to find the max/min value. In this case, you have no choice but to generate all combinations and compare which is the best. if the resulting set of combinations is very large, you may want to use some kind of pruning to reduce the search space.

Comment: Not really, although it looks the knapsack problem, it isn't. What's different here is ony one product combo is needed. It depends on how long the PartCombo list is. All that's needed is to go through that list, see if that combo's list is a subset of the the given list, and if so if it's the biggest power so far. So we're filling one knapsack, not working out how to split things across multiple ones https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: How is this related to Scala?

Comment: The important factor is whether the PartCombo's are explicitly defined or there may exist a PartCombo for  any random combination of parts ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, we're told by the OPthere is a list of combinations of parts.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul there could be many product combos for a given list of parts, not just one.

Comment: Yes, but you say " I need to choose the one that products the most power"  That implies you just want one. If you're actually after the set of combos that produce the most total power from your list of parts, that is a restatement of the knapsack problem.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Yes the most optimal set of combos (if there are more than one) that produce the most power, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Then @Mox hasthe right idea and you have a variant of the (NP-complete) knapsack problem